# How to find out which javascript library owns $

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with javascript still, but I would like to know how to check if a library is supposed to be using $ and then do an if statement off of it. Sorry if I have a hard time asking this!

Comment: Do you need to detect WHICH library is using it, or just if it is being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test if two object are the same with the `===` operator:

```
if ( $ === jQuery ) {
  // $ is a reference to jQuery
}
```

Comment: $ === window.jQuery would work better in case jQuery isn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to tell if it is jQuery

```
if($(document.body).jquery){alert("yep");}
```